# Subscriber of Room's DAO method returning Flowable is not notified about inserted entities

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I have a Room database with one entity and DAO, which allows inserting objects and observing `SELECT` query as `Flowable`. When I subscribe to this `Flowable` and, then, insert a new object to database, new results are not emmited.

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
abstract class TestDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao: UserDao
}

@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert
    fun insert(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
    fun observeUsers(): Flowable<List<User>>
}

@Entity
data class User(@PrimaryKey val id: Int, val name: String)
```

A failing test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ObserveUsersTest {

    @Test
    fun observeUsersTest() {
        val db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), TestDatabase::class.java
        ).build()
        val dao = db.dao
        val user = User(0, "George")
        val test = dao.observeUsers().test()

        dao.insert(user)
        test.assertValue(listOf(user))

        db.close()
    }
}
```

The failure:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: [User(id=0, name=George)] (class: SingletonList), Actual: [] (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0)
```

Test passes if inserting is done before calling to `observeUsers`:

```
    dao.insert(user)
    dao.observeUsers().test().assertValue(listOf(user))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you don't wait long enough to observe the result of the insertion. If `insert` is asynchronous internally (even though you didn't define it with an RxJava API), you could be subscribing and testing for a single value too early.

Try using the [`awaitCount`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#awaitCount-int-java.lang.Runnable-long-) tester-method before asserting a single value (as you have a infinite `Flowable` so `awaitTerminalEvent` doesn't work of course):

```java
dao.observeUsers()
.test()
.awaitCount(1, TestWaitStrategy.SLEEP_10MS, 5000)
.assertValue(listOf(user));
```